# How to make webview produce cursor (pull up keyboard) by tapping any place inside webview xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I embedded webview in my UWP app to present information and allows user to edit it, however in the phone I found that it will pull up the input keyboard and cursor only by typing the first line when there is one line content or no content, I'm wondering how to allow user type anywhere in the webview to pull up keyboard and show the cursor.

Comment: what do you mean by 'typing the first line when there is one line content or no conent'? What do you have in webview page?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks! It means that when I try to type in the webview so that it can produce cursor and pull up keyboard, I can only type the first line, if I type other places like the middle of the webview, then it will not pull up the keyboard and show the cursor(If there is already some contents, I can type the area with contents, but below contents, typing doesn't pull up keyboard nor show the cursor).

Comment: I made a demo using `textarea` in webview page, but didn't reproduce the problem. Maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?